# Categories not showing when calling block in magento

Tags: php, css, magento

I am calling a static block using the pages CMS functionality in Magento.

It's calling it, but the categories are not showing whenever I call it.

this is what I added in the design tab of the CMS

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnavig" before="-" template="catalog/navigation/left_menu1.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

On the other hand, The code for my menu is :

```
<div class="box layered-nav"> 
    <div class="head">
      <h3><?php echo $this->__('Browse By') ?></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="border-creator">
      <div class="narrow-by">
           <dl id="narrow-by-list">

         <dd>
           <ol>        
        <?php 
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
        $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();

            foreach ($cats as $category_id) { 
                $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id) ;

            ?>
            <dt>
            <?php       echo $_cat->getName(); ?>
            </dt>
        <?php } ?>

       </ol>
      </dd>
      </dl><script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list')</script>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

what is wrong? do I need to add a helper or something that I forgot?

Answer (score 0):

Just remember this is using the non-anchor style of category viewing,  if the categories are set as anchor, this view type is not applicable. Additionally, a simple but sometimes missed issue.  You have to make sure that the home page is set to use 2columns-left or 3 column layout.  Otherwise your referencing a block that you have turned off.  Everything appears to be correct code wise.

Comment: I actually needed it converted into anchors, I actually just used that as a sample. If I want to actually use anchors, what kind of syntax should I use?

Comment: The block type should be 
     <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>   This will reference the layered nav block type.